# Symfony: Using global variables

Tags: php, symfony, global-variables

I know... stay away from globals.

The thing is I really, really, need to have a value that is accessible and, most important **modifiable** from different parts of the application. It's a counter for some actions that I need to watch for debug purposes. Googling for anything related to Symfony and globals, always got me to results that suggests using the Container parameters or Twig globals, but the thing is that according to Symfony documentation:

> You can only set a parameter before the container is compiled: not at run-time.

The Twig globals are pretty much out of scope given that I need them in controller, not in view.

IMHO, both of these solutions are more like constants than variables.

So, the question is: Is there a best practice to obtain what I need using Symfony or should I just use the PHP globals?

Thank you!

Comment: Store it in session? Make service and get this service from container?

Comment: Create a service with a  private property $counter and a setter and a getter to set or get the value. A service class will be instantiated automatically and can be reached from everywhere where you can use the container. I think you could even write a destructor that stores the new value when Symfony terminates. http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

Comment: Thanks, using a service sound like the proper way. Please post an answer!

Comment: @MaxDamage Is this something you want? [Dynamically creating a global twig parameter in controller and access it in twig template](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5kr1/dynamically-creating-a-global-twig-parameter-in-controller-and-access-it-in-twig-template)

Comment: @BentCoder not quite. I didn't needed in twig, I needed to be application-wide and modifiable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a service (e.g: `ApplicationGlobals`) with a private property `$counter` and public setter and getter to read and write the value. A service class will be instantiated automatically and can be reached from everywhere where you can use the container (get it in the controller or pass it as an argument to other services).

Latter you will be able to add multiple variables, when needed, with their proper getters and setters and use them in your project.

I think you could even write a destructor that stores the new value when Symfony terminates. http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the **parameters** section in **services.yaml** ?

It seems that you can also define/modify variables programmatically :

```
$container->parameters()->set('app.admin_email', 'something@example.com');
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters

Comment: I guess based on the second note here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/service_container/parameters.html#getting-and-setting-container-parameters-in-php saying `You can only set a parameter before the container is compiled: not at run-time.`, so while you can set the value, you might not be able to update it during run-time, which is more like a constant than a variable.