# How do you declare php supper global const from with in a include file in side of a class function?

Tags: php, constants, global-variables

I am using Symfony v 2.8, and it uses bundle class functions to process web-page requests.

I've created an include file that I load with a **require** statement that isolates the code that I use to create several of variables that I use though my web-app, such as the path of my web-app, whether the site is running in the development or production environment, and the URI of the web-site that was navigated from to get to a page in my web-site or between the pages in my web-site.  Currently, these variables are local to the function that **required** the include file, so I have to re-include the file in each function that needs these variables.

My goals are:

1. Include this file only in the bundle xxxxAction function that is
   executed to handle the web-page request.
2. After being created in the bundle xxxxAction function, have the
   variables *seen* in-scope in all of the functions that the bundle
   xxxAction function calls or the functions that they call, without
   needing to prefix them as **SELF::**, like **_POST** works.
3. In the functions other than the xxxAction bundle function, I'd
   rather not have to use the **global** statement or the $GLOBALS
   associative array.
4. Have these variables read-only or constants, so that they can't be
   modified after set in the include file.

My site has a number of pages, and each has its own bundle Action function, and each of these **require** the include file.

I already looked at [Variable scope at php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) web-site, but unless I missed something, I didn't see how to create Supper-Global read-only variables.

Here is the code that I'm using to create the local variables:

```
$request = $this->get( 'request_stack' )->getCurrentRequest();
$session = $request->getSession();

$context = $this->container->get( 'router' )->getContext();

$site    = $this->get( 'request' )->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

//
// The regular expression checks if the referring web-spage's URL matches one of
// following:
//
//    http://mysite.name.com/app.php or
//    http://mysite.dev.name.com/app_dev.php or
//    https://mysite.name.com/app.php or
//    https://mysite.dev.name.com/app_dev.php.
//

$isFromMySite = ( preg_match( '/https?:\/\/mysite.(dev\.)?name.com\/app(_dev)?.php/',
                              $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] ) === 1 );

// baseURL: /app{_dev}.php  True  = Development Environment, False = Production Environment.

$baseURL = $context->getBaseUrl();

$isDev   = ( $baseURL == '/app_dev.php' );
$isProd  = ( $baseURL == '/app.php' );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025856/8721909

Comment: Thanks fbuchlak.  I suppose that a service would work, but it seems like a lot of work just for a few global constants.  I had a feeling that rather than simple constants, I was actually going to need a class with setters and getters to protect the values after they were set, but an entire service was more involved than I was thinking.  I'm probably going to have to leave this issue alone for a bit, while I wrap up my project for its initial release in a few days before digging into this.  Incidentally, what does php offer in way of global constants?

Comment: You could create simple class just for constants and call it anywhere. For example App\MyClass::CUSTOM_CONST

Comment: Yes, I'm tending towards that.  However, when I'm using several Symfony class bundles/controllers, and add my own static class in which to store my own global values, won't the static class defined in one bundle/controller be different than the static class with the same name in another bundle/controller?  If not, then how global are the static classes that I create?  I don't want them so global that they are seen by the different users of my web-app or even the same user who is running two copies of the same page in their browser.  No cross-talking is wanted here.